# Applying for Additional Quota for YouTube API as an Individual (without business info)

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, quota, youtube-livestreaming-api

I recently began using the Youtube Data v3 API for a program that I'm writing which is purely for personal use. To give a brief summary of what it does, it checks the the live chat from my most recent (usually ongoing) livestream and performs actions based on certain keywords entered in chat (essentially commands for people to use from live chat). In order to do that, however, I have to constantly send requests to get a refreshed livechat. As it is now, it sends requests on 1 second intervals. I recently did a livestream to test out my program and it only took about 25 minutes for me to reach the daily quota limit of 10,000 units/day.

The request is:`youtube.liveChatMessages().list(liveChatId=liveChatId,part="snippet")`

It seems like every request I make costs 6 units, according to the math. I want to be able to host livestreams at lengths of up to 3 hours, which would require a significant quota increase. I'm aware that there is an option to fill out a form to request additional quota. However, it asks for business information such as a business name, business website, business mailing address, etc. Like I said before, I'm doing this for my own use only. I'm in no way part of a business, and just made my program as a personal project. Does anyone know if there's any way to apply for additional quota as an individual/hobbyist? If not, do you think just putting n/a in those fields would be acceptable? I did find another post where someone else had the exact same problem, but no one was able to give a helpful answer. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am having the same issue and would also like to know more about the experience of others with requesting more quota (especially) for the YouTube Live API. But it seems nobody could help the other person and nobody can help here either :(

Comment: I am mostly using Youtube API v3 search function which costs 100 units per request. currently having a daily quota of 10.000 units that sucks. I only use this for a custom app for my mom. I'm willing to pay for a much higher quota, is that even possible?

Comment: even i am willing to pay, but they should tell the cost involved and how to do it. Again, i am an individual and this is really distressing.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, and although only related, it seems as Google is for the money here. I also tried to do something similar myself (a very basic chat bot just reading the chat messages), and, although some other users on the net got some different results, they all have in common that, according to the doc how it should be done, all poll at this interval of about once a second (that's the timeout one get as part of the answer to a poll for new messages). I, along with a few others, got as most as about 5 minutes with polling once a second, some others, like you, got a few more minutes out of it. I changed the interval by hand in incrementing intervals of 5 seconds each: 5, 10, 15, etc... you get the picture. I can't remember on which value I finally tuned in, but I was only able to get about 2 1/2 hours worth with a rather long polling interval of just once every 10 seconds or so - still way enough for a simple chat bot just reading the chat. But also replying would had at least doubled the usage and hence halfed the time.

It's already a pain to get it working as an idividual as just setting up the required OAuth authentication requires one to at least provide basic information like providing a fixed callback and some legal and policy information. I always ended up in had it rejected with this standard reply "Your project seem to be for internal use only.". I even was able to got this G suite working (before it required payment) to set up an "internal" project (only possible if account belongs to a G suite organization account), but after I set up the OAuth login I got the error that my private account I wanted to use the bot on was not part of the organization and hence can't be used. TLDR: Just useless waste of time.

As far as I'm in for this for several months now there's just no way to get it done as a private individual for personal use. Yes, one can just set it up and have the required check rejected (as it uses the YouTube data API scopes), but one still stuck with that 10.000 units / day quota. Building your own powerful tool capable of doing more than just polling once every 10 to 30 seconds with just a minimum of interaction doesn't get you any further than just a few minuts, maybe one or two hours if you're lucky. If you want more you have to set up a business and pay for it - simple and short: Google wants you to pay for that service.

As Mixer got officially announced to be shut down on July 22nd you have exactly these two options:

1. Use one of the public available services like Streamlabs, Nightbot, etc ... They're backed by their respective "businesses" and by it don't seem to have those quota limits (although I just found some complaints on Streamlabs just from April - so about one month prior to when you posted this question where they admitted to had reached their limits - don't know if they already got it solved).
2. Don't use YouTube for streaming but rather Twitch - as Twitch doesn't have these limits and anybody is free to set up an API token either on the main account or on a second bot account (which is also explicitly explained in their docs). The downside of this are of course the objective sacrifices one has to suffer: a) viewers only have the quality of the streamer until one reaches at least affiliate b) caped at max 1080p60 with only 6.000kBit/s c) only short time of VOD storage

I myself wanted to use YouTube as my main platform (and currently do, but without my own stuff at the moment) and my own bot stuff and such as streaming on YouTube has some advantages over Twitch, but as YouTube wants me to pay what others (namely: Twitch) offer me for free (although overall not as good quality) it's an easy decision to make. Mixer looked promissing, as it also offered quite some neat features (overall better quality than Twitch, lower latency), but the requirements to get partner status were so high (2.000 followers along with another insane high number to reach) and Mixer itself just so little of a platform (I made the fun to count all the streamers and viewers - only a few hundred streamers with just a few 10.000s viewers the whole platform had less than some big Twitch channels on their own) - and now it's announced soon to be dead anyway.

Hope this may give you some input into what a small streamer has to consider and suffer from when chosing a platform - but after all what I experienced I have these information: Either do it like all the others: Stream on Twitch and use YouTube as an archive to export to from Twitch (although Twitch STILL doesn't have an auto-export of the latest VOD implemented - but I guess that could be done by some small script) - or if you want to stay on YouTube use some existing bot like Nightbot or any of the other services like Streamlabs.

If you get any other information on how to convince Google to increase the limit as an individual please let us know.

Comment: Following here, just in case there is any update. Seems youtube is still more of useless thing here. THey dont provide any details on costing wieghtage. I am also building a chat bot, for personal chats. I could not even find an option to pay as well. The form is hell lot complex. Is there any support or working forum to request for ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70594746/youtube-data-api-wrongly-calculated-quota-exceeded/70595099?noredirect=1#comment124797879_70595099

Comment: Well, it hasn't changed a bit since. Google still enforces this 10k unit quota for any unregistered project. If you want to get more you have to set up a company gsuite account (warning: it cost money!) and then still have to apply for an increase request with a good reason as for why you should get granted more qouta. I since tried twitch - but as they refuse to fix their oauth endpoint to meet rfc and their recent security breach I stopped bother to dev my own bot. If you want to save yourself a lot of trouble: Use one of the bots out there and live with they access private account data.

Comment: Yes, sadly the limit is virtually useless for most applications. And this hasn't changed. The ticket was raised but they were quick enough to close it as well. Also, the current request form is something that seems to deter and intentionally reject. Bots i have started with TWidget, which seems to be open source, but that also relies on closed source backend, and don't feel good giving full access to yt account. I have  Google workspace and cloud account but still can't get it working.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70594746/youtube-data-api-wrongly-calculated-quota-exceeded/70595099

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I haven't used stack lately. I understand why google has locked down the api that tightly - but I don't understand why they make it so hard to apply for some usefull rates. Just contacting them with a simple request like "I'd like to write my own yt live chat bot" only gets you the semi-auto reply "please sign up for g-suite". And since M$ shut down mixer (which was nice while it lasted) there's no competitor to YT and twitch unless you host one your own. If you have a look at all the rest of googles api for some the 10k quote isn't enough for one complete request.

Comment: i already have a Workspace and GCP account, sadly, not much useful