# Youtube Data API Wrongly Calculated, Quota Exceeded

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I have a very simple message and getting the v3 youtube data api to get the list of comments. I am just fetching the list of videos and then fetching the comments (at frequency of 5 sec) to get updated messages. using the page token as needed to minimize the load and computaion.

Today after some time while internally testing the application i started getting the **quota exceeded exception**. I know the youtube provided by default 10000 units and since reading the comments (and videos as well) is just 1 unit, i should expect to get similar numbers.

However, the data is wrongly calculated.
Following are request details
[image]
If you see, there are 2895 total requests LiveChatMessages-> List.
However, when i go to IAM-> Quotas, it showed 14k earlier, then 12.6k in quota usage
[image]

There seems to be some problem either with the computation or with the Documentation that defines the units for queries. Can someone help please..
PS: Just using the two apis as mentioned above in screenshot. Both are list.

Answer (score 1):

> If you see, there are 2895 total requests LiveChatMessages-> List. However, when i go to IAM-> Quotas, it showed 14k earlier, then 12.6k in quota usage

Yes i can see that there are 2895 requests, but how do you know what the qutoa costs are for those requests.   You are using the [YouTube Live Streaming api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started) for those requests. Not the [YouTube-Data-api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)

There is no documentation of the quota cost for the YouTube Live Streaming api calls.  If Google says you used all your quota then you probably have.

I would post an issue over on the issue forum asking them to document the quota cost for the calls [Issue forum](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803)

Comment: @dalmTo if you see the following page, it clearly states that live streaming api also uses the similar costs and included in the page. But since there is no seperate mention on the page, is it not implied that they converge.
I understand i used all the cost, but there should be some documentation or guideline for me to see where the problem is.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost

I am just thinking, how do commercial applications of similar nature do that, i am polling at much lower rate, Do i need to req quota raise  even for that ??

Comment: Also, my only req is to read the comments. So if you or someone can help me how to optimize my instant issue would be solved. thanks in advance

Comment: While I agree that the doc states **calls to those methods also incur quota costs**  Im not seeing them in that page are you?   If you are at 80% of the quota then you should request additional quota.   Asking why your hitting the quota is a waste of time IMO just get more (●'◡'●)

Comment: @DalmTo, got, your point. My bad, i read it will counted, and i INFERRED ( i erred) that it converges with base apis. The thing is right now i am working on POC and there can be multiple iterations, projects. The form that is provided for quota request is NOT SO friendly, i can try that, but its tedious process. Since i am just "reading" comments, expected it to be a bit more. ATM i dont know how much more to request for, unless some wieghtage is there.

Comment: @DalmTo this is a long and standing issue. Can you give some guideline if possible. Use case is a chatbot type thing for personal streams of 3-4 hours.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61281991/applying-for-additional-quota-for-youtube-api-as-an-individual-without-business

Comment: Check this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/213311835

Comment: Hi, thanks for this raising this, but i am sorry to say the response from google team is not so great, seeing they marked is obselete, when the issue is never done. 1. the claim to be similar, but they DONT have the same cost unit apparently, comments in normal video incur 1 unit, here its 100. 2. the process is for raising the quota is apparently something which is deterrent for most ppl. (have a look at the form)  3. The current quota  is virtually useless for almost all use cases, atleast for  live streaming.  Thanks anyways for raising.